# Get content from facebook by hashtag

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

Why is there information about facebook hashtags if it's not supported by the graph API? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/hashtag Is there a way to get images and content by hashtag?

I.e #summerhangout:

```
/* PHP SDK v4.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/%23summerhangout'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

Result:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message '(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: #summerhangout' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/projname/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php:134
Stack trace:
#0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/projname/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php(280): Facebook\FacebookRequestException::create('{"error":{"mess...', Object(stdClass), 404)
#1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/projname/helper/facebook.php(127): Facebook\FacebookRequest->execute()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /Library/WebServer/Documents/projname/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php on line 134
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why is there information about facebook hashtags if it's not supported by the graph API?

It is stated in the first line

> Information about hashtags. Used in Facebook's Trending APIs

Trending API is a whitelisted feature only available to a select few companies.

> Is there a way to get images and content by hashtag?

Yes using the Trending API.

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/%23summerhangout'
);
```

This should be using the `hashtag-id` which was stated in the documentation.

So the hashtag id for `#summerhangout` is 147811522058338

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/147811522058338'
);
```

I am not even sure why you are calling this edge when the documentation tells you that the only fields you will get here is the name and the id (which you already know)

```
{
  "id": "147811522058338", 
  "name": "#Summerhangout"
}
```

Comment: Ok, so no, it's not possible to get images and content from the API by hashtag if the only thing returning is the Name and Id. How did you get the Id for the Hashtag?